# jQuery hover() second callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` element with a class name `event-element`. When I hover the element I want it to display the text "Mouse over!". When I click the element I want it to display "Clicked!" I have this working so far with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.event-element').hover(function(event) {
        $('.event-element').text("Mouse Over!");
    });
    $('.event-element').click(function(event) {
        $('.event-element').text("Clicked!");
    });
});
```

However, on the second callback of hover, I need the text to display "Mouse Left!" implying that the mouse is no longer hovering over the element. Any advice on how to make this work is appreciated.

Comment: Reading manual really helps: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: You seem to already know how to do it (use the second callback to `hover`), so...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.hover()` binds both mouseenter and mouseleave events. So you would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.event-element').hover(
        function(event) {
            $('.event-element').text("Mouse Over!");
        },
        function(event) {
            $('.event-element').text("Mouse Left!");
        }
    );

    $('.event-element').click(function(event) {
        $('.event-element').text("Clicked!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `hover` which provides callback for mouseenter as well as mouseout. And secondly, inside the function, you can use `$(this)` instead of specifying `$('.event-element')` again. Below is the working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.event-element').hover(function() {
    $(this).text("Mouse Over!");
  }, function() {
    $(this).text("Mouse Left!");
  });
  $('.event-element').click(function() {
    $(this).text("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='event-element'>element</div>
```

Comment: No, he/she doesn't. *(not my dv)*